# Angular2 + karma test + redux - process is not defined

Tags: unit-testing, angular, redux, karma-runner, ionic2

I am trying to implement karma unit testing possibilities with my Ionic2 rc1 (using angular 2.0.0) application that's based upon angular2-redux. 
The karma setup is basically adopted from the following repo:
https://github.com/lathonez/clicker and works fine. I have a simple counter redux implementation working fine as well. When I try to setup angular2-redux for my testing, I get the following error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
  at webpack:///Users/luki/Applications/ionic/ionic2-redux-example/~/redux/es/index.js:14:0 <- src/test.ts:65041

I know process is not defined in the browser but only available for node on the server. How do I need do adjust my karma config to be able tu use angular2-redux ?

Calling the createAppStoreFactory function to provide my AppStore in TestBed.configureTestingModule causes this error.

My test setup can be found in the following repo:
https://github.com/lujakob/ionic2-redux-example/blob/master/src/test.ts

Any help appreciated!

(the npm angular2-redux has a demo app and a sample test setup. But this relies

Comment: I know it's old, but... you found a solution? I'm running into this error with karma + redux, too...

Comment: Sorry, it's very specific and years old. Can't remember at all.

Answer (score 6):

Even if it's almost a three year old question, for anyone else facing this problem, here's my solution:

As `process` is only defined in NodeJS but not in the browser, we have to tell karma that it should 'fake' it.

Create a javascript file and give it a name as you wish (for example `global-variables.js`) with the following content:

```
const process = {
  env: {
    NODE_ENV :'production'
  }
};
```

In your `karma.conf.js`, import this files as the **FIRST import** in the `files[]` array:

```
(...)
files: [
    './test/global-variables.js',
    { pattern: config.grep ? config.grep : 'test/**/*.test.ts', type: 'module' }
],
(...)
```

That should fix at least the `ReferenceError: process is not defined`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, i have been looking for a solution to this problem for a while now. And this is the first working solution. Kudos!! and thanks